# Tengo que realizar una consulta con fechas y horas pero la verdad no sé cómo hacerle

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net

Tengo este problema:

Tengo que hacer un reporte con parámetros de fecha y hora específicos en Visual Studio
y se me ocurrió usar un datagridview el tema es el siguiente:

```
Sub consultatatablas(tabla As DataGridView, fecha1 As Date, fecha2 As Date)
        adaptador = New SqlDataAdapter("select Folio, fecha, Servicio, total from ventas where fecha between '" & fecha1 & "' and '" & fecha2 & "' ", conexion)
        Dim dataS As New DataSet
        adaptador.Fill(dataS, "ventas")
        tabla.DataSource = dataS.Tables("ventas")
    End Sub
```

Las fechas deben ir así en la consulta de sqlserver '04-05-2021 07:00:00'
y el usuario debe elegir los rangos de fechas y horas.

El problema principal es que si el usuario consulta el mismo día da un error pues no puede declarar la hora inicial ni la hora final.

Uso dos Datatimepicker
Este es el código de la forma con el datagridview:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    consultatatablas(DataGridView1, CDate(DateTimePicker1.Text), CDate(DateTimePicker2.Text))

End Sub
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Agrega un try y un catch a tu método para ver cual es el error especificamente

Comment: como que da un error? te salta una excepción en tiempo de ejecucion? Si es asi podes verlo en la ventana de salida.

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.' Ese error me da. Entiendo que es por los valores Date, pero no sé cómo poder convertir o hacer algo para que tome las horas.